# I am using parse.com PHP SDK . In login can I set additional parameters other than username and password

Tags: parse-platform

My parse server user object has additional column called "status" using PHP SDK login i want to check status set to 1 along with username and password

Comment: Your question is not clear. Let us know what you have done and be precise.

Comment: i am using parse PHP SDK. It's login method has two parameters username and password. I want to check additional paramter like status what I have already added in user object while adding it. How I can pass that extra parameter in login method

Comment: show us your current code

Comment: @mqpasta $request = $this->request(array(
    'method' => 'GET',
       'requestUrl' => 'login',
       'data' => array(
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password
                               'AdditionalColumn'=>$additional value
       )
   ));

Comment: can you make it part of your question?

Comment: As of now  parse PHP SDK has following login method                               $data = ['username' => $username, 'password' => $password];
        $result = ParseClient::_request('GET', 'login', '', $data);            Now  I want to pass extra argument in $data array. My qustion is can I do it ?